# The parameter list is repeatedly passed in C function that accepts a variable number of arguments

Tags: c, objective-c, variadic-functions

My OC code is written like this:

```
NSString * CMLocalizedString(NSString *key, ... ) {
    va_list valist = NULL;
    va_start(valist, key);
    NSString* value = va_arg(valist, id);
    va_end(valist);
    
    NSLog(@"key = %@, val = %@", key, value);
    
    return key;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    CMLocalizedString(@"SSS", nil);
    CMLocalizedString(@"BBB", @"555", @"333", nil);
    CMLocalizedString(@"AAA");
    CMLocalizedString(@"CCC");
    
    return 0;
}
```

But my console output is like this

```
key = SSS, val = (null)
key = BBB, val = 555
key = AAA, val = 555
key = CCC, val = 555
```

Why does `va_list` received duplicate values?

Comment: I know next to nothing about Objective C so I'll just ask: Does this have anything to do with C as well? If not, the tag should be removed.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 `CMLocalizedString` and `va_arg` are a C, not Objective-C.

Comment: @张贵广 The C experts are confused. Remove Objective-C by replacing the `NSString*`s by `Int`s and `NSLog` by `printf`.

Comment: @Willeke I get that it's undefined behavior. I suppose the use of variadic arguments being the main issue means that it is related to C in a way, but I'm not entirely sure if it should be tagged C still. Kinda like a C++ question which is having an issue with a C function or C API but the code is still C++. (On a side note, this question has been asked a bunch of times at least for C, there's probably a duplicate for this somewhere).

Comment: The `stdarg.h` macros cannot tell you the number and type of the arguments, so calling `va_arg` when you didn't pass an additional argument is undefined behavior. You should design your program in a way that you can derive from the `key` argument how many additional arguments you expect or at least if you expect a next argument and its type.

Comment: Another option would be to define your function interface to require a `nil` argument after 0 or more non-`nil` arguments. Then you can use `va_arg` until you find a `nil` value. (similar to the interface of `execl*` functions)

Comment: It' s just one of the `shot the leg` cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `CMLocalizedString` expects a second argument. In the last two calls you don't pass a second argument, so you cannot expect a certain behavior from the function. That an argument from a previous call seems to be printed in place of the missing argument is just coincidence, likely due to still lying around at the same memory address.